# Why multiple blender animations are not showing up in unity when imported

Tags: animation, armature, unity, dopesheet

I have followed numerous online tutorials and no matter how many times I watch/mimic exactly what they are doing, I still end up with ONE animation that plays everything at once. I cannot figure it out. Basically I just have two buttons and I would like them to be able to be pressed separately. I have created a left and right armature to control the left and right buttons, but no matter how many times I link/relink the animations or double check that only one animation is linked per armature, they still both press at the same time. A little insight on this would be greatly appreciated. [Here is a dropbox link to the blend](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/11224660/HUD.blend), I just want it fixed and to know what I am doing wrong. So lost right now.

Watched [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gb152Qncn2s) tutorial. Seemed great, but doesn't seem to help me out any.

This is what the import looks like. As you can see, only the "RightButtonAction" animation.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't have unity to check but I see a difference that may help.

The right armature has keyframes on the bone (done in pose mode)

The left armature has keyframes on the armature itself (done in object mode)

It may be that unity doesn't support object animation on armatures which are expected to be animated in pose mode.